# need split the left side '/' charcter in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a query in SQL 2014

```
SELECT [orde_reference],
SUBSTRING([orde_reference], 
CHARINDEX('/', [orde_reference]) + 1, 
LEN([orde_reference])) AS batch FROM   Orders
```

That returns the following

input is ,86156161566156/454

Result need

86156161566156 only

Thanks

Comment: Hi please have you always the same input like : ,[number suite x][/][some other number]   if it's the case you can try this : SELECT SUBSTRING(RIGHT(@Var,LEN(@Var)-1),1,CHARINDEX('/',@Var)-2)

Comment: is the comma actually there?

Comment: but in case alphabet came that alphabet is removed

Comment: incase i  have data L114512515151/456  i need L114512515151

Comment: ok so you excepted result : 114512515151 for the input L114512515151/ ?

Comment: yes but i got answer                                                                                                       Select left([orde_reference],charindex('/',[orde_reference]+'/')-1)

Comment: i think the answer doesn"t work with your relevant example ... ,86156161566156/454 provided ==> ,86156161566156 and in your request your excepted 86156161566156

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps `left()` would be a cleaner option

```
Select left([orde_reference],charindex('/',[orde_reference]+'/')-1)
```

Comment: @sivaprakash.s Always happy to help.  notice the +'/' in the charindex portion.  This is a fail-safe if there is no slash  :)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the first part of the string, than you're using the wrong values.  The first parameter of substring is the string that you want to transform, the second parameter is the starting position, and the third is the end position.

```
SELECT [orde_reference],
SUBSTRING([orde_reference], 
0,
CHARINDEX('/', [orde_reference])) AS batch FROM   Orders
```

This should do it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT LEFT(orde_reference, CHARINDEX('/', orde_reference) - 1) AS batch
FROM Orders;
```

Here is a link for different string manipulations in SQL Server: https://datatofish.com/left-right-substring-sql-server/